# Regex pattern match with hbase output

Tags: python, regex, python-re

we are trying to find a pattern match from hbase output data.

string:

```
s1=' -0123456789 column=col_fam:col_qlf, timestamp=1865789098799, value=abcd'
```

re match expression:

```
re.match(r'(.+)column=(.+), timestamp=(.+), value=(.+)')
```

we are getting output as below:

```
match=' -0123456789 column=col_fam:col_qlf,'
```

can you please help me to fix the issue?

Comment: The regex seems working for your input. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xFwiyz/1), you need to use it as `results = re.match(r'(.+)column=(.+), timestamp=(.+), value=(.+)', s1)` and then you may see `results.groups()`

Comment: This is not what I get, please share the code you use, how to you obtain `match` ?

Comment: re.match(r'(.+)column=(.+), timestamp=(.+), value=(.+)',s1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

(I'm unsure of your output requirement ... perhaps update the question to reflect.)

```
import re

exp = re.compile(r'^(.+)\scolumn=(.+),\stimestamp=(.+),\svalue=(.+)$')
s = ' -0123456789 column=col_fam:col_qlf, timestamp=1865789098799, value=abcd'
m = exp.match(s)

# Test match was found.
if m:
    # Show output (if required).
    print(m.groups())
```

#### Output:

```
(' -0123456789', 'col_fam:col_qlf', '1865789098799', 'abcd')
```